# What are the differences between an API App and a Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-apps

What are the differences between an API App and a Logic App?

Development speed ... e.g. the LA designer response gets very slow

Deployment options ... both through ARM template

Testing options ... API App is Web API, so all usual good testing practices, but Logic App doesn't have anything

Security options ... Logic App's can set "Allowed inbound IP addresses" to specific IP's

Any other differences ?

Answer (score 2):

Azure API Apps are used to host your own, custom Web APIs in the cloud.

Azure Logic Apps allow you to implement workflow process without requiring you to write any code through the use a a visual, "no-code" style designer.

If you look at the documentation on how to use these services you will see the differences quite clearly.

Comment: I was looking for any of the gotcha's of one versus the other

Comment: @SteveC That is not the question you asked. If you have specific questions, please ask additional questions here on SO.